# OpenX, Weird Broken Banner

Tags: ads, openx

I'm having a weird behavior at one of my zones, the thing is that no banner is showing for a big % of the time, instead, a broken image icon shows up.

Opening the OpenX delivery url I got this HTML.

> www.myopenxserver.com/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=15&source=3342&target=_blank&cb=13099352342

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> 
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'> 
<head> 
<title>Advertisement</title> 
<style type='text/css'> 
body {margin:0; height:100%; background-color:transparent; width:100%; text-align:center;}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<a href='F' target='_blank'><img src='F' border='0' alt=''></a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I checked the zone at the openx panel and open each banner linked to the zone, every single one was working properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the banner zone (...afr.php?zoneid=15&source...) on the URL didn't exist... and looks like OpenX sends you that HTML response when the zone doesn't exist. I don't know if it is because of the debug mode or it is like this.